# Concatenate variable with a string to define another variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in a JavaScript

say like this

```
var divId = 2;
```

now I want to define some variable which will be like this

```
var day_2_0 = $("#rules_" + divId + "_offer_number").val();
```

but I dont want to define `var day_2_0` straightforward.

I want something like this, if at all possible

```
var day = "day_"+divID+"_0";
```

so that `var (var day) => var day_2_0;`

Is anything like this possible in JavaScript?

---

`NOTE`: its something equivalent to this php snippet

```
$offer = "offer1";
$$offer then means $offer1
```

so if we write `echo $$offer;` then it means `echo $offer1;`

Comment: sorry, it's unclear to me....

Comment: what's wrong with `var day = "day_"+divID+"_0";` ????

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there are 2 ways you can do it:

1.eval (maybe avoid this one), i.e.

```
eval('var day_' + variableHere);
```

2.use an object

```
 var someThing = {};
    someThing['day_' + variableHere];
    // then get the value by
    someThing.day_variableValue;
```

Google `eval` for a million opinions on its use